# Creating Layer from Selection in ArcGIS Online

Tags: arcgis-online, select

I am trying to create a layer from a selection using a layer I have hosted in ArcGIS Online. I have run into 2 issues: I'm not able to select multiple features on the map (only by scrolling thru the attribute table) and I cannot see how to create the new layer.

To select multiple features I have tried holding down the shift and/or control buttons but only the first feature I touch is selected. For example, if I want to use the cursor to select a group of points I seem to be unable.

[image]

Comment: there a public link?

Comment: There is a Select Widget that can be added > https://doc.arcgis.com/en/web-appbuilder/create-apps/widget-select.htm#GUID-65B24BE2-5879-4615-9A62-5D17588FF573